# Count points per polygon, classify point count in original layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer, intersection, point-in-polygon, count

I have a question that I believe is similar to [Count points in polygon grouping by attribute using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/362436/count-points-in-polygon-grouping-by-attribute-using-pyqgis) but not really the same, as I would like to do it without PyQGIS and also have the information added in one of the original layers, instead of a new one.

In my case, I have a point-layer which contains several points with a lot of data (columns). There is one column that is most significant, as I need the points classified according to that column.

[image]
[image]

I also have a polygon-layer containing a buffer.

I now wish to count the points within each polygon and I want the count and classification to be added (in the original buffer-layer if possible), so that each class gets its own column, which then contains the count for this particular class in the buffer.

If the buffers overlap and the point falls into several buffers, the point should count for each buffer.

---

**EDIT:**
What I meant with the last statement: When 1 point falls into 3 buffer-polygons for example, I would like each polygon to recognise the point and note down "1", instead of perhaps just couting it once for the first polygon and then ignoring it for the other polygons, or counting it thrice for one polygon and not at all for the other overlapping polygons.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Using field calculator with expressions you can create a new integer field on your polygonlayer with the expression:

```
array_length(
  overlay_intersects(
    'pointlayername',
    $id,
    filter:="fieldcontainingcategory"='nameofcategory'
  )
)
```

Repeat this as many times as you want the count of different categories.

Instead of `overlay_intersects()` you can also use `overlay_contains()` depending on the method you wish.

Comment: I tried your code for Overlay_intersects() and although it goes through without error messages, the count is off when buffers overlay. From looking at some example areas, it seems that when a points falls into three buffer-polygons for example, the point is counted three times for one polygon.

Comment: Well you said "If the buffers overlap and the point falls into several buffers, the point should count for each buffer", thats what it does.

Comment: I see now how that is a misleading statement of mine. What I meant is simply that each buffer recognises this point and counts it, instead of only counting it once for the first polygonlayer and then ignoring it in every other overlaying polygon. So, let's say a point falls into 3 overlaying buffer-polygons. Then I would like each polygon to note down "1".

Comment: Is there a way to eliminate the double count? I have edited my original question to make my statement/request clearer. I have since tried other overlay-functions (touches, within and crosses) which usually counted 0.

Comment: I cannot think of a way fulfilling this condition using expressions. But you can do this with PyQGIS, just as I did in [ProcessX Plugin's](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ProcessX/) algorithm [Count Points In Polygon With Condition](https://github.com/mkoenigb/ProcessX/blob/main/algorithms/vector_conditionals/CountPointsInPolygonsWithCondition.py). Using the Plugin you need to run the algorithm as often as you have different categories.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this using a virtual layer.

Go to the menu `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` and enter the following query. Modify `pt.cat` for `pt.nutzart` (the name of your category field) as well as the name of the layers. It assumes the polygon primary key is called `id` (maybe change it to `oid`)

This query will keep all fields from the polygon and count the points for each specified category. You can then persist the layer if you wish.

```sql
select p.*, 
    count(case when pt.cat='category A' then 1 else null end) cnt_a,
    count(case when pt.cat='category B' then 1 else null end) cnt_b,
    count(case when pt.cat='category C' then 1 else null end) cnt_c,
    count(case when pt.cat='category D' then 1 else null end) cnt_d
from myPolygonLayer p
join myPointLayer pt
 on st_intersects(p.geometry, pt.geometry)
group by p.id
```

Comment: One correction on my part. The relevant column isn't 'nutzart' but 'neue_bez'. I have tried your code and ran into two problems. One seems to have to do with the '/' in the class name. But when I remove that, I get a very long error message, stating the layer is invalid because: (...) 1 - near "from": syntax error".

Comment: make sure the statement just before the `from` is properly written (including *no* comma at the end).

Comment: I have corrected my mistake and the code went through! Sadly, the count is off as well whenever polygons overlap. I have updated my original statement regarding the specifications of counting as it might have been misleading. Any idea how to archieve that way of counting or why the counting is off right now?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pretty quick PyQGIS solution for your updated question. It adds x new fields to the polygon layer naming them `count_nameofcategory` and adds the count of each category. You can also set that a point is only counted once, if so, it will only be counted for the first polygonfeature ordered by featureid. You can implement an iteration order if you want to change that. Note that it uses `QgsSpatialIndexKDBush`, so it will only work with 2D-SinglePoints. I am aware the script is not perfect and can be improved, but for now just change the first 4 lines to your needs and run it:

```py
### Settings:
polygonlayer = iface.activeLayer()
pointlayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('points')[0]
fieldwithcategories = 'category'
countpointonlyonce = True

### no changes needed ###
attrvaluesdict = {}
categories = []
req = QgsFeatureRequest().setFlags(QgsFeatureRequest.NoGeometry).setSubsetOfAttributes([fieldwithcategories], pointlayer.fields())
for feat in pointlayer.getFeatures(req):
    categories.append(feat[fieldwithcategories])
    attrvaluesdict[feat.id()] = feat[fieldwithcategories]
categories = set(categories)

pointlayer_idx = QgsSpatialIndexKDBush(pointlayer.getFeatures())
pointlayerskip = []

with edit(polygonlayer):
    for cat in categories:
        polygonlayer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField('count_'+str(cat), QVariant.Int)])
        polygonlayer.updateFields()
    
    for feat in polygonlayer.getFeatures():
        for cat in categories:
            feat['count_'+str(cat)] = 0
            polygonlayer.updateFeature(feat)
        featgeom = feat.geometry()
        featgeomengine = QgsGeometry.createGeometryEngine(featgeom.constGet())
        featgeomengine.prepareGeometry()
        intersectingpoints = pointlayer_idx.intersects(feat.geometry().boundingBox())
        for ipoint in intersectingpoints:
            if ipoint.id in pointlayerskip and countpointonlyonce is True:
                continue
            pointgeom = QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(ipoint.point()).constGet()
            if featgeomengine.intersects(pointgeom):
                pointlayerskip.append(ipoint.id)
                category = attrvaluesdict[ipoint.id]
                feat['count_'+str(category)] += 1
                polygonlayer.updateFeature(feat)
```