# Counting in field calculator with several group_by- and filter-conditions

Tags: qgis, polygon, field-calculator, point, count

My question relates to a work-around that I assumed might work, instead of trying this: [Count points per polygon, classify point count in original layer in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/438947/count-points-per-polygon-classify-point-count-in-original-layer-in-qgis/438953?noredirect=1#comment717407_438953) as all counting attempts have either failed or returned a wrong count number.

I have a layer with polygons (buffers), each polygon has been assigned a unique ID (IDBuffer).
I have a second point-layer with the column "neue_bez", in which there are three classes (Kultur, BildungHochschule, NaherholungFreizeit) and a column that assigns each point a unique ID (IDBaupoint), too.

I want to know how many points of each class are within each polygon and I need this information added to the original polygon-layer in three columns (one for each class of "neue_bez"). I know I can get the raw information from a statistic by category, selecting IDBuffer and neue_bez like so:

[image: example of my statistic by cat]

But as mentioned, I would like a column added for each of the three classes, containing the count for that class per polygon.

This far, I have already intersected the two mentioned layers, so that I now have a layer that contains both IDs (IDBuffer, IDBaupoint), as well as the column "neue_bez" and thus the three classes.

[image]

I have since tried the following functions in the attribut table, to create a count-column for the class "Kultur" from the column "neue_bez"- for each polygon

```
sum(count("neue_bez", group_by:="IDBuffer", filter:="Kultur"))
```

This just returns 0 for every row.

---

I tried

```
count("neue_bez", group_by:="IDBuffer")
```

But this just returns the overall count of points per polygon and doesn't classify them.

---

Lastly, another idea I had was:

```
sum("neue_bez",group_by:="IDBuffer",filter:="Kultur")
```

Which doesn't work/is invalid, because right now I'm asking it to sum up "neue_bez", although the content is not numerical. If I created a column that just held the value "1" in each field to represent the amount of entries, could this then work, including the two expressions of group_by and filter?

Are there more elegant ways of doing this than my last idea?

Comment: Have you tried using `overlay_intersects()` with the `count()`-part as expression on the unprocessed polygon layer?

Comment: I have tried something similar with the overlay-function: array_length(overlay_intersects('pointlayername',$id,filter:="fieldcontainingcategory"='nameofcategory'))
But the count was never right when I checked for overlapping polygons. Could you specify your approach please, if it differs from this one?

Comment: If the count is incorrect with this function check if both layers are in the same CRS

Answer (score 1):

Use QGIS expressions with [`overlay_contains()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-contains) with the following pattern on your polygon layer to get the number of points from layer `points` with attribute `Kultur` that has a value of `14`:

```
array_length(
    overlay_contains(
        'points',  -- replace with name of your point layer
        $id,
        filter:=Kultur=14  -- replace with attribute name/value
    )
)
```

*Expression inserted as dynamic label: the large number counts how many points with attribute `Kultur`=14 each polygon contains:*
[image]