# Counting points in hex grid by attribute in QGIS

Tags: qgis, spatial-join, overlapping-features, point-in-polygon, count

I'm trying to count points within a polygon layer (hexagonal grid), grouped by an attribute of the points. There are some solutions on here (Python console, SQL virtual layer) but I can't seem to get it to work.

An example to illustrate:

Points:

| ID | Attribute |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | A |
| 5 | B |

The output I want for example:

| polygon | countA | countB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 13 |
| 3 | 6 | 2 |

I've tried this: [Count points in polygon grouping by attribute using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/362436/count-points-in-polygon-grouping-by-attribute-using-pyqgis) but the counts come back as `0` everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a possibility of using a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`.

Let's assume there is a point layer called *'Random points in polygons'* and a polygon layer called *'municipality_1'* with their attribute tables.

[image: input]

With the following query, it is possible *to count points within a polygon layer, grouped by an attribute of the points.*

```sql
SELECT poly.*, countA, countB, countC
FROM "municipality_1" AS poly

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT poly.id AS idA, count(1) AS countA
    FROM "Random points in polygons" AS poi, "municipality_1" AS poly
    WHERE st_within(poi.geometry, poly.geometry)
      AND poi.attribute = 'A'
    GROUP BY poly.id
    ) ON poly.id = idA

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT poly.id AS idB, count(1) AS countB
    FROM "Random points in polygons" AS poi, "municipality_1" AS poly
    WHERE st_within(poi.geometry, poly.geometry)
      AND poi.attribute = 'B'
    GROUP BY poly.id
    ) ON poly.id = idB
    
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT poly.id AS idC, count(1) AS countC
    FROM "Random points in polygons" AS poi, "municipality_1" AS poly
    WHERE st_within(poi.geometry, poly.geometry)
      AND poi.attribute = 'C'
    GROUP BY poly.id
    ) ON poly.id = idC
```

The output polygon layer with its attribute table will look like this:

[image: result]

Answer (score 5):

Use the following QGIS expression on the polygon layer to get the number of features in layer *'Points'* with the value of the field called `"attribute"` = `A`:

```
array_length(overlay_contains('Points', $id, filter:=attribute='A'))
```

*Label generated by concatenating the above expression three times for A, B and C:*

[image]